# How do you compile a C program?

Tags: c

This might be the most newbie question ever, but how do you compile a C program?

I’ve downloaded the source of a C program (ffmpeg, to be precise). How do I compile it?

Comment: When you looked for an online tutorial in C programming, what did you find?  Anything helpful?  Did you -- for example -- try using Google to look for a quick C tutorial?  If so, what questions do you have on the tutorial you found?

Comment: Does it come with a MAKEFILE? If so, just type `make`.

Comment: what OS are you using? Maybe there's a README or something like that with instructions.

Comment: There is probably a README file included with the source you downloaded - I expect it tells you how to build it.

Comment: FFmpeg is seriously not the place to start when it comes to compiling C programs.  This is about four hundred times more true if you're trying to build on Windows.

Comment: Yes, this is the most newbie question.  What's your operating system?

Comment: @S.Lott: didn’t look, I asked on Stack Overflow first — figured I’d get better results that way, and that those results would be saved for anyone else who searched, or asked the same question.

Comment: @sled @Dima: I’m on Mac OS X, 10.6.

Comment: So... you asked before reading their documentation (unless they don't have any documentation)?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: they didn’t have any documentation about how to compile (that I could find) on the website. The answer here that mentioned documentation could be found in the INSTALL file is pretty helpful.

Comment: @ladenedge: yeah, I got a fairly cryptic error on my first go, definitely looks like more experience would be helpful.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: "I got a fairly cryptic error on my first go, definitely looks like more experience would be helpful.".  That's my point.  "those results would be saved for anyone else who searched".  Yes, the result is that it's hard and more experience is helpful.  Not really a stellar answer.  Specifics and focus are more important than broad and vague.  As nice an idea as it seems, "newbie" questions like this really demand a lot more background than can be provided in a "simple" question.

Comment: @S.Lott: yup, and now the next person that asks it will know that.

Comment: @Paul: Your "fairly cryptic error" is likely to do with some dependency you don't have installed. Consider using [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) unless you really want to build by hand. I'm a fink guy myself.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: "the next person that asks it will know that"?  Know what?  That you get cryptic errors?  How's that helpful?  Wouldn't it be better to have perhaps read something, tried something and then posted the cryptic error?  Wouldn't that be focused and specific?  And therefore specifically helpful to them AND you?

Comment: @S.Lott: no, they’ll know that compiling ffmpeg is hard and more experience is helpful. Telling individual askers like me that a question isn’t specific enough doesn’t do anything to stop the other 6 billion people on earth from asking more specific questions. Having this particular unspecific question here tells other people with the same unspecific question that they need to be more specific, and that they should check the INSTALL file, i.e. it’ll help stop this unspecific question from being asked again.

Comment: @Paul: I have to say that I think your question isn't well constructed. The right answer to *"How do I compile a c program?"* is not the same as the right answer to *"I've downloaded a major third party software package as source, now what?"*. And for all that this is a very common problem we get relatively few version of this question, because most "Download it" pages have instructions right under the link to the tarbal (either inline or as another link).

Comment: @dmckee: I totally see what you mean. I did actually intend to ask the more general question though (i.e. how do I compile any C program, not specifically how do I compile ffmpeg). General questions are difficult to answer, but without knowing something about compiling C programs, I didn’t know how general the question was.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: "General questions are difficult".  Close.  They're essentially *impossible* to answer.  They require a tutorial.  Hence the zero upvotes on the question.  It's so hard to answer, we're commenting on it to try and get you to either fix it or delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most Unix-style C programs, the incantation is:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This should already be documented in the `INSTALL` file, which additionally may contain further useful information.

Comment: Though to be fair, the actual compile command is probably `cc` or `gcc` and to compile a single file program it would probably look like `cc helloWorld.c`

Comment: @Frustrated: That's true, but the OP didn't mean that. He meant "How do I build this project I downloaded?"

Comment: Hopefully there is also a `make test` for the project. To be done before the install command.

Comment: @Martin York: There is; the OP should have RTFM http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 2):

For a single file just cc file.c (or gcc or whatever you C compiler is called)

For a complex project like ffmpeg, then either make, cmake, configure some other. Check their documentation

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what OS and compilers you have, but typically the sequence is:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

to compile simple math program, it's not enough to <include math.h>. See

```
gcc file.c -lmath -o program_bin
```

for a single .c file using ffmpeg libraries, it can be made this way:

```
gcc -Wall -g live_segmenter.c -o live_segmenter -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lbz2 -lm -lz -lfaac -lmp3lame -lx264 -lfaad -lpthread -I/home/devicer/ffmpeg/include -L/home/devicer/ffmpeg/lib
```

notice -L and -I options. In serious projects they are usually set by pkg-config.

for the ffmpeg itself..
 - install lame, few other required libraries, then do as Chris said.
Btw, sometimes it requires gmake, not make.

Also, have a look on

```
./configure --prefix /home/devicer/ffmpeg
```

This is what was mentioned (used for) in segmenter compilation above.