# : syntax error near unexpected token `('?

Tags: c, linux, gnu

Can anyone tell where the problem is?

```
someone@someone:~/Desktop$ cat morning.c
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  printf ("Good Morning") ; 
  return 0;
}
```

```
someone@someone:~/Desktop/9raya$ ./morning.c
./morning.c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./morning.c: line 2: `int main (int argc, char** argv)'
```

I really don't see where the problem is.

Comment: You need to compile the c code first. ``gcc filename.c -o filename``

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you compile a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661251/how-do-you-compile-a-c-program)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to execute C source code and your shell doesn't understand that. You need to compile the source code into an executable, then execute it. For example,

Compile `morning.c` to produce an executable named `morning`:

> gcc -Wall -Wextra morning.c -o morning

Execute `morning`:

> ./morning

where I added the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags to provide a more useful set of compiler warnings on top of gcc's quite minimal default.